# rndc: connect failed: 127.0.0.1#953: connection refused

Tags: centos, bind, named

This is a very annoying problem that i am having with the `rndc reload`

I am getting the following error:

```
rndc: connect failed: 127.0.0.1#953: connection refused
```

However the following work fine,

```
[root@cbgfx ~]# service named restart
Stopping named: .                                          [  OK  ]
Starting named:                                            [  OK  ]

[root@cbgfx ~]# tail -f /var/log/messages
Aug  7 12:51:09 cbgfx named[31990]: zone 120.88.167.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 14
Aug  7 12:51:09 cbgfx named[31990]: zone 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
Aug  7 12:51:09 cbgfx named[31990]: zone domain.com/IN: domain.com/MX 'mail.servergreek.com' has no address records (A or AAAA)
Aug  7 12:51:09 cbgfx named[31990]: zone domain.com/IN: loaded serial 14
Aug  7 12:51:09 cbgfx named[31990]: zone localhost.localdomain/IN: loaded serial 0
Aug  7 12:51:09 cbgfx named[31990]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 0
Aug  7 12:51:09 cbgfx named[31990]: managed-keys-zone ./IN: loaded serial 4
Aug  7 12:51:09 cbgfx named[31990]: zone domain.com/IN: sending notifies (serial 14)
Aug  7 12:51:09 cbgfx named[31990]: zone 120.88.167.in-addr.arpa/IN: sending notifies (serial 14)
Aug  7 12:51:09 cbgfx named[31990]: running
```

The vps has `ipv6` ip address, is there anything i missed here?

Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I fixed it myself , it was a permission and ownership issue.To fix it you need to execute those ssh commands

## Fix rndc connection refused error

`chown root:named /etc/rndc.key`

`chmod 640 /etc/rndc.key`

Comment: or in ubuntu, `chown root:bind /etc/bind/rndc.key`

Comment: This only worked for me after I restarted bind9.  `service bind9 restart`

Answer (score 6):

clear the file of directory **/var/cache/bind/** and after in terminal bash
**/etc/bind/bind9 restart**

Answer (score 2):

The problem might not only be in rndc.key.

The easiest way to detect is running:

*service named restart*

Check if there is any error, if there is an error, run:

*systemctl status named.service*

Check any permission denied error. It could be in the log files as well.

Comment: In my case, I need to change permission to zone folder (named) to named

Answer (score 0):

In my case as bsentosa comment I needed start process named, you can enable to named start together within system

```
$ systemctl enable named
```

Comment: Waht is "caso as bsentosa"? I think the question is poor quality already: Obviously when named is *not* running, you cannot tell it to reload. So the question should be "how do I start named"? IMHO too trivial to ask here...

Answer (score 0):

I am on Mac OS X (Ventura), with `Bind9` installed through `Brew`. I ran into the same issue. I had to run `named` with `sudo` to make this error disappear: It was an ownership issue.

Also, you should pay attention to `named` logs, sometimes you have just errors in your `*.zone file`.

I hope it will help Mac users landing here.